# how to hide the title of tabbar item while selecting the tabbar item in UITabviewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I need to show the selection `image` in `tabbar` item without the `title`.

Is there a possibility to hide the title at the time of selection?

here is my code

```
let icon1 = UITabBarItem(title: "Title1", image: UIImage(named: "homenormal")!.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal), selectedImage: UIImage(named: "home")!.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal))
let icon2 = UITabBarItem(title: "Title2", image: UIImage(named: "usernormal")!.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal), selectedImage: UIImage(named: "user")!.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal))

dashboard = DashboardViewController(nibName: CommonClass.DeviceType.IS_IPAD ? "DashboardViewControlleriPad" : "DashboardViewController", bundle: nil)

userMain = UserMainViewController (nibName : CommonClass.DeviceType.IS_IPAD ?  "UserMainViewControlleriPad" : "UserMainViewController", bundle : nil )

tabbar = UITabBarController()
tabbar!.viewControllers = [dashboard!, userMain!]
dashboard!.tabBarItem = icon1
userMain!.tabBarItem = icon2
window!.rootViewController = tabbar
window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Comment: can you show some code, it helps to give answer.

Comment: you can just temporarily make the title of the tab you are selecting @"".